# Centos6 не загружается

Tags: grub

Centos6
После не штатного отключения, не грузится система, ошибка:

```html
GNU GRUB version 0.97 (623K lower / 3668976K upper memory)

[ Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB
lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists the possible
completions of a device/filename.]
grub>
```

Подскажите, как исправить.

Answer (score 0):

В моём случае помог fsck разделу c boot.